# Do NY Metrocards with money ever expire?

Tags: public-transport, money, new-york-city

Are there any instances when the yellow metrocard with money loaded on it ever expire?  Or can I use it 10 years later?

Comment: By the time you use it 10 years later it may barely be enough for a single ride. :)

Answer (score 9):

[Quoting from the MTA FAQ](http://web.mta.info/metrocard/problems.htm#expired):

> Whether Pay-Per-Ride or Unlimited Ride, every MetroCard has an expiration date. The date is located at the upper left corner on the back of the card. The expiration date is usually about one year from the date of purchase.
>
> If your Pay-Per-Ride MetroCard expires, you have two years from the expiration date to transfer any remaining money to a new card. Within the first year after expiration, bring your expired card to any subway station and ask the agent to make the transfer. After that time, the expired MetroCard must be sent to MetroCard customer claims. Ask the station agent for a postage-paid Business Reply Envelope.
>
> MetroCard Customer Claims
>
> 130 Livingston Street
>
> Brooklyn, NY 11201

Comment: Damn, wish the policies were like Paris' card!

Comment: @verve Well, theoretically, the [MetroCard is being retired](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/02/25/nyregion/after-mta-setbacks-no-swipe-fare-cards-are-still-stuck-in-the-future.html), though current gossip puts the implementation of mobile phone and/or contactless smartcard final retirement date [around 2022](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/01/the-slow-agonizing-death-of-the-metrocard/384722/). So it would be just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they expire. Even the time period to send them to MTA Headquarters for trade is limited, and I got burned. I believe they were accepted for trade for one year past the printed expiration, which was the last date the fare gates would accept them.

As far as I am concerned the MTA owes me about $15.

Comment: Downvoter: anything to say for yourself?